# yii2 how to override configuration per module

Tags: yii2

I am trying to build a yii2 application that uses frontend framework (in my case riotjs if it matters). For this, the yii2-app-basic and yii2-app-advanced was not really fitting my needs, so I created my own structure in the following way:

```
/controllers
    /IndexController.php
/modules
    /v1
        /Module.php
        /users
            /Module.php
            /controllers
        ...
/themes
    /v1
        /layouts
            /main.php
        /index
            /index.php
        /partials
            /navpanel.js
        /assets
            (bower assets here because it is still in the dev phase)
/config
    /main.php
    /main-local.php
/public
    /index.php
    /assets
```

The configuration related to this problem:

```
'defaultRoute' => 'index/index',
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '_api/<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'
        ]
    ],
    'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'index/index'
    ],
    'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'basePath' => '@app/themes/v1',
            'baseUrl' => '@app/themes/v1',
            'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/v1']
        ]
    ]
],
'modules' => [
    'v1' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\v1\Module'
    ]
]
```

So, all the backend logic is stored inside submodules, which are versioned by their parent module. This allows me to create new versions for the api modularly. The same goes for themes. The rule that exists in the url manager is to prefix all the modules with `_api/`. The default route and error handler dispatches to the same action because riotjs will handle the errors (for example, if someone opens the browser and goes to a route that doesn't exist, first the riotjs template will get rendered and then the riotjs will show a dialog that "page doesn't exist").

Now this is where I am stuck. I want to have different configuration for both parent modules and submodules. I want the main modules to have a different, JSON based error handler. Secondly, I want to keep all the URL rules inside submodules. So, REST rules for the module user will reside in the module, not in main configuration file. If I store these rules in main configuration, the design loses it's intended modularity.

How can I override these configurations per module?

Comment: So for `v1` module you need a set of configuration and `user` module needs a whole different one ?

Comment: User needs the config of v1 and also some other configs. For example, if I add error handler to module v1, I want the error handler to also work in user

Answer (score 3):

In Module.php

```
public function init()
{

    parent::init();
    Yii::$app->setComponents(require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));
}
```

and config.php example:

```
return [
   'response' => [
      'format'=>'json',
      'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
   ],
];
```